# Match vectors of different length by their maxima and get indices

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have variables

```
A = [40 67 68 70 66 65 99 90 65 20 21]
B = [1  1  2  3  1]
```

How to get indices if `A` by matching the maxima of `B` and `A`?
So imagine I slide with `B` over `A`, stop when the maxima match, and then I'd like to get the "position" of `B` by means of the according indices of `A`.

desired result :

```
4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: How do you come to that result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of many:

```
A = [40 67 68 70 66 65 99 90 65 20 21] 
B = [1 1 2 3 1]

%// maxima
[~,mA] = max(A(:))
[~,mB] = max(B(:))

%// result
mDiff = mA - mB
idx = ( mDiff + 1 ) : ( mDiff + numel(B) )
```

Comment: @user3752566 if it was helpful don't comment - upvote it.

Comment: @thewaywewalk excellent mentalist skills. When seeing this I still do not understand how it relates to the question, but obviously it work for the asker :)

Comment: @patrik in doubt, assume the most simple case ;)